# Как вы читаете документацию на английском?

Tags: документация

В последнее время, приходится читать много документации на английском. Так как язык я знаю плохо, через раз пользуюсь гугл переводчиком. Метод рабочий, но далеко не самый удобный.

Возникла у меня идея, переводить документации к популярным фреймворкам/либам и продавать её по подписке. Ну например,  понадобилась документация по mongodb, купил доступ за 200р и нормально читаешь не ломая глаза и мозг.

Как считаете возможно ли на этом, что-то заработать? Купили бы вы такое? И как вы читаете доки сейчас?

Comment: Я на 40% читаю, что-то на русском, на 60% что-то на английском. Идея в целом хорошая. Переводчиком пользуюсь редко, если уж ну вообще сложные и непонятные слова.

Comment: Непонятно одно. Вы сами говорите, что язык знаете плохо. Как тогда собираетесь переводить для продажи?

Comment: Идея интересная. Думаю есть будущее. Но сам пользоваться не стал бы. (Может, это мои личные тараканы в голове, но мне кажется, разработчик обязан уметь читать документацию на английском). А ведь разработчики либ/фреймворков наверное имеют какие-то права на свою документацию к ним, разве нет? Разрешат ли они так зарабатывать на ней?

Comment: в технической литературе, особенно в документации, словарный запас нужен весьма скромный. имхо идея провальная. во первых популярные фреймворки и либы и так имеют переводы, во вторых чтобы подписки покупали нужен очень хороший перевод, что сложно сделать если вы плохо знаете язык, и особенно сложно сделать хороший перевод, если вы не знаете сам предмет (а если вы читаете доки, значит вы его не знаете). В третьих, вы вероятно не пробовали переводить документацию и статьи, это весьма затратное по времени занятие, которое требует труда не одного человека.

Comment: с этой точки зрения `how-to` статьи куда интересней

Comment: ruSO все больше Тостер напоминает... По сабжу - толк от русской документации? Без примеров ничего не стоит. Читаю чаще всего на английском (хоть и знания не очень, но хватает), т.к. на русском шлак из-за доморощенных SEO-шников.

Comment: Периодически встречаются такие русские переводы какой нибудь документации, что легче читать первоисточник на английском (даже при том, что я то же плохо знаю язык), просто потому, что пытаются дословно переводить предметную терминологию. Так что переводчик вам понадобится очень крутой, с хорошим знанием предмета, о котором он пишет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю английского, мне это не мешает читать документации на английском, гугл переводчик в помощь, а так же очень часто достаточно взглянуть на примеры и все понятно.

1. Думаю подписками ты не чего не заработаешь. Так как:

   - постоянно выходят апдейты и документация меняется
   - фреймворков очень много и постоянно появляются новые (Покупать подписку из за монги ну не найс)
   - Люди не знающие английского все реже встречаются, особенно программисты
   - МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ, что руссификация доки может понадобится только на этапе знакомства с либой, а когда ты не знаешь ты выбираешь инструмент и из за попробовать покупать подписку не найс.
2. Я бы в жизни за это не платил бы
3. Мне в 70% случаев достаточно примеров, в 20% гугл переводчик, в 10% мое убогое знание английского на уровне когда читаешь отрывками словосочетаний

Answer (score 5):

Если человек не знает английский и не может что-то прочитать, то очевидно делать ему нечего в программировании, так как там ВНЕЗАПНО все на английском и думать надо на английском, и писать на английском. Все это конечно весьма упрощенно, но если спокойно пишешь и понимаешь код, то проблем с документацией не будет.
Ответы на вопросы довольно просты и очевидны:

1. Возможно что-то заработаешь, но надо понимать, что надо поддерживать актуальность документации, без этого она ничего не стоит, а значит один ты не справишься. А неактуальная документация никому ненужна.
2. Лично я не купил бы и не знаю людей кто купил бы.
3. Какие есть те читаю ища по ключевым словам нужные места.